# Adding Quote around an existing string in multiple files

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I want to add a double quotation around an existing string in a multiples files.

> check_envurl!ma100mlpapl002!-p 8080!-u /apollo/info?section=ERROR!!!!!

I want to add a quote after the first "-u" but before the / and before !. So it would be

> check_envurl!ma100mlpapl002!-p 8080!-u "/apollo/info?section=ERROR"!!!!!

I've tried with sed replacement but doesn't meet the criteria

```
define service {
        host_name                       ma100mlpapl002
        servicegroups                   Environment URL
        service_description             http://ma100mlpapl002:8080/apollo/info?section=ERROR
        display_name                    http://ma100mlpapl002:8080/apollo/info?section=ERROR
        check_command                   check_envurl!ma100mlpapl002!-p 8080!-u /apollo/info?section=ERROR!!!!!
        max_check_attempts              3
        check_interval                  15
        retry_interval                  1
        check_period                    24x7
        contact_groups                  siteops

    sed '/pattern/a some text here' filename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sed 's/-u \([^!]*\)!/-u "\1"!/' <<< 'check_envurl!ma100mlpapl002!-p 8080!-u /apollo/info?section=ERROR!!!!!'
check_envurl!ma100mlpapl002!-p 8080!-u "/apollo/info?section=ERROR"!!!!!
```